# Overriding a class in Manim

Tags: python, manim

I'm trying to remake the constructor of this class in Manim by passing some Latex as an argument (either through function or console), but I haven't been able to. How can I override it?

```
from manim import *

class WriteStuff(Scene):
    def __init__(self, milatex):    
        super().__init__()  
        self.milatex=milatex 
      
    def construct(self):
        example_tex = MathTex(self.milatex)
  
        self.play(Write(example_tex))
        self.wait()
```

Comment: What happens if you tun it?

Answer (score 0):

Usually not recommended, you should have a data center where `milatex` can be stored and retrieved. If you must, you can use a python script to start it.

```
# test.py
from manim import *

class WriteStuff(Scene):
    def __init__(self, milatex):    
        super().__init__()  
        self.milatex=milatex 
      
    def construct(self):
        example_tex = MathTex(self.milatex)
  
        self.play(Write(example_tex))
        self.wait() 

with tempconfig({"quality": "medium_quality", "preview": True}):
    scene = WriteStuff(r"\xrightarrow{x^6y^8}")
    scene.render()
```

Then from console start with:

```
python test.py
```